# When creating virtual-host, apache would work only with /var/www/html/ directory

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, lamp, permission-denied

I just moved from WAMP to LAMP, and can't figure out this problem that I am facing. 
Whenever I create new vhost which is not in this directory `/var/www/html/` i get a 403 forbidden message. (Permission are the same and there is an index file)

It seems to me that somewhere in Linux you specify a list of directories and apache works explicitly with those ones.

I use Apache 2.4.6.

I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the error log(vhost), I found this error message "search permissions are missing on a component of the path".
Meaning that one of the parent directories from where the vhost was located didn't not have search (+x) permission for the apache user.